# Central console antivirus for Linux computers in LAN or equivalent solution

Tags: linux, antivirus, logging, administration

In our company, we **need** by policy AVs on every developers' Linux (Mint) computers.

Right now we have ClamAV running on them, daily scheduled scans and every developer manually sends the report log to the SecMan. Not ideal.

I'd like to know if a centralized AV console exists for Linux, that ideally is free, offers a central point for alerts, logging, etc, and we don't have/won't have Windows computers.

In case there aren't, what solutions do Linux-based LAN SysAdmins use? At least, I'd need scripts or setups that put every box's log into a central repository, mailbox (`scp`? `sendmail`?), even kibana, but I'm not happy opening that central box for "listening to incoming stuff", even when it's on our own LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but Sophos Central supports Linux, providing Central cloud-based management of Linux, without using any Windows at all.